# Could an upgraded Ubuntu cause problems?

Tags: ros, odroid, rplidar, rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had previously used Ubuntu 20.04.4 on an Odroid M1 without any issues. Compiled and successfully used a few packages of ROS including rosbridge and rplidar. Since the update I have not been able to execute `rosrun` as it says the files are not executables. In the time I have not changed any of the ROS directories and not been working on them. I always source before hand but the problem remains.

Could these issues be attributed to the upgrade of Ubuntu and if so how can I get my projects working again?

In the mean time I have tried reflashing the image so the packages must be installed again. `Catkin_make` completes successfully but nothing will execute.

At the moment all attempts at `rosrun xxx xxx.launch` return the error:

```
odroid@gnome-desktop:~$ rosrun rosbridge_server rosbridge_websocket.launch
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named rosbridge_websocket.launch below /opt/ros/noetic/share/rosbridge_server
[rosrun] Found the following, but they're either not files,
[rosrun] or not executable:
[rosrun]   /opt/ros/noetic/share/rosbridge_server/launch/rosbridge_websocket.launch
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/406205/could-an-upgraded-ubuntu-cause-problems?/) by [Pieter90](https://answers.ros.org/users/108451/pieter90/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-09-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `rosbridge_websocket.launch` is a lunch file. Therefore, please use `roslaunch` instead of `rosrun` as shown below:

```
roslaunch rosbridge_server rosbridge_websocket.launch
```

---

Originally posted by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) with karma: 1744 on 2022-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-09-10**:
@ravijoshi Good catch!

**Comment by [Pieter90](https://answers.ros.org/users/108451/pieter90/) on 2022-09-10**:
Okay great that works perfectly now for rosbridge_server. There is a new problem that arose now in that it doesn't work for built packages from the catkin_ws. Trying to launch my rplidar with the sae command and as suggested in the official documentation (http://wiki.ros.org/rplidar). The following error occurs:

```
odroid@gnome-desktop:~$ roslaunch rplidar_ros rplidar.launch 
RLException: [rplidar.launch] is neither a launch file in package [rplidar_ros] nor is [rplidar_ros] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

The same happens with Hector_slam. This is after I have sourced both catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash and /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-09-10**:
@Pieter90 Please create a new question. The site guidelines encourage a "one question / one answer" approach. You can include a url back to this question if it helps understand the new question.